# What's the opposite colour to "green" for a native thread?

Tags: multithreading, terminology

Simulated threads are known as "green threads" in programming-language-wonk speak. They are compared to "native threads" as provided by the operating system, but is there an analogous colour for native threads, and what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User-mode threads can be referred to as "green" threads, whereas kernel-mode threads can be referred to as "red" threads. This terminology is rarely used, but an appreciation of the difference is a good thing to know.

Comment: What would be the origin of this?

Comment: @Thorbjørn I do not know the exact etymology, it's just distinctions I remember from OS study at Uni. I can say that given the context of my study the terminology is quite old.

Comment: Never heard the term, perhaps I'm too young :)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Lucky you :)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. The "green" is like in "green peace", not like in "green apple". I guess the opposite might be "smoggy" or any other term denoting non-eco-friendliness.

Answer (score 1):

how about "taste" instead of color -- native threads can be ***"bitter threads"*** :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is not too far afield.  Colors do not have 'opposites' they have complements.  The complement of green is magenta.